# Check uniform continuity of functions

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

Pick out the uniformly continuous functions:

$$
\begin{array}{lll}
(a) \quad& f(x) = \cos   x \cos \pi x                   & x \in(0, 1)\\
(b)      & f(x) = \sin   x \cos \pi x                   & x \in(0, 1)\\
(c)      & f(x) = \sin^2 x                              & x \in(0, \infty)\\
(d)      & f(x) = \cos   x \cos \left(\frac\pi x\right) & x \in(0, 1)\\
(e)      & f(x) = \sin   x \cos \left(\frac\pi x\right) & x \in(0, 1)\\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: *Hint:* Any $\mathcal{C}^1$ function with bounded derivative is Liptschitz, hence uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 3):

We can solve these by knowing these things

> Let $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb R$ be a function that is continuous on the bounded, open interval $(a,b)$. Then the two limits
>   $$\lim_{x\to a_+}f(x)\qquad\text{and}\qquad \lim_{x\to b_-}f(x)$$
>   exist if and only if $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(a,b)$
>   *Theorem 1.12 in The calculus integral by Brian S. Thomson*

and

> If a function $f$ has a bounded derivative, it is [Lipschitz continuous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity).
>   All Lipschitz continuous functions are uniformly continuous.

---

$$(a)\quad f(x)=\cos x \cos(\pi x),\quad x\in(0,1)$$
The derivative of this function is
$$f'(x)=-\sin x\cos(\pi x)-\pi \sin(\pi x) \cos x$$
This functions derivative is bounded by $[-\pi-1,\pi+1]$, hence it's Lipschitz continuous.

---

$$(b)\quad f(x)=\sin x\cos (\pi x),\quad x\in(0,1)$$
The derivative of this function is
$$f'(x)=\cos x\cos(\pi x)-\pi \sin x \sin(\pi x)$$
This functions derivative is bounded by $[-\pi-1,\pi+1]$, hence it's Lipschitz continuous.

---

$$(c)\quad f(x)=\sin^2 x,\quad x\in(0,\infty)$$
The derivative of this function is
$$f'(x)=\sin(2x)$$
This functions derivative is bounded by $[-1,1]$, hence it's Lipschitz continuous.

---

$$(d)\quad f(x) = \cos x\cos\left(\frac\pi x\right),\quad x\in(0,1)$$

The limit below is undefined, hence the function is not uniformly continuous

$$\lim_{x\to0_+} \cos x\cos\left(\frac\pi x\right)=\color{gray}{\text{undefined}}$$

---

$$(d)\quad f(x) = \sin x\cos\left(\frac\pi x\right),\quad x\in(0,1)$$

The limits below are defined, hence the function is uniformly continuous

$$\lim_{x\to0_+} \sin x\cos\left(\frac\pi x\right)=0$$
$$\lim_{x\to1_-} \sin x\cos\left(\frac\pi x\right)=-\sin 1$$

Comment: What if the functions are f(x) = cos x cos (π/x)
, x ∈(0, 1) and g(x) = sin x cos (π/x), x ∈(0, 1) ?

Comment: @user127444 I have updated my answer to include all of the cases.